# Reporting Service add new language

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I want create new language pack for reporting services but I don’t have any idea what I should do. I tried to create folder with the shortcut for the language that I want to create and copy from other folders files and put them into this folder but this failed. Another idea was to create a backup for English version and change some phrases but page don't react to that. I tried to do this in this directory:

...\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10_50.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportManager

Please help.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Do you mean create a language pack or install a language pack? The MS reference on language support in SSRS is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156493(v=sql.100).aspx), does it help?

Answer (score 0):

The [report manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157147%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) will [use your client browser language](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156493%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) to determine the localization for the web interface. Some relevant info from the linked article:

> Both the client application (usually a browser) and the operating system of the computer that is running the report server play a part in determining which language resource is used.

The available languages are the ones that are available to SQL server (see the same linked article, further down). As far as I can tell there's no way to extend this list with a new language by providing translations.

An alternative (but far more labor intensive) way to go at that would be to create your own web or windows application with the ReportViewer, and create that app in the locale of your choosing.